# Why did Ben and Kalam save Hairlock?

Tags: books, malazan

In the first book of `Malazan Book of the Fallen` series, `The Gardens of the Moon`, `Ben` and `Kalam` save `Hairlock` just in time. My questions are:

1. How was the arrangement made between Hairlock and Ben?
2. The Bridgeburners were devastated in the mines and no way in position of thinking others, I guess. So, why did they save (soul-shift) him?
3. This is not in the title but I want to ask nevertheless. Why did Ben want Hairlock dead even though he saved him?

PS: This is my first question. I hope I did not violate any rules regarding spoilers.

Comment: i took a stab at answering this for you, let me know if you want some clarification on anything, the books are very vague so this is the jist of why they did what they did, though the books never spell it out for you. Especially when it comes to quick ben after 10 books you still never learn who he really is, or how powerful he really is.

Comment: @Himarm Thank you for telling me that QB is going to live for all 10 books :)

Comment: Its hard to answer questions without spoilers in this series haha, i tried to not spoil much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Malazan book of the Fallen Series is very vague on certain points, but ill try to give you a full answer.

1. Hairlock was assigned to go into the tunnel that the BridgeBurners where building underneath the walls of Pale, before the final attack on Pale. During this its mentioned he had talked to Quick Ben, who offered to soul shift him should he get injured or die, Or Hairlock himself approached quick Ben as he was also from the seven cities and would have learned, or suspected that Quick Ben knew how to soul shift, as Quick Ben himself contains the souls of some 7+ people.
2. Quick Ben needed someone who could safely traverse the paths of Chaos to spy on ShadowThrone. This was the primary purpose Quick Ben used Hairlock for, essentially to confirm that Shadowthrone was the emperor or not. Quick Ben also used Hairlock to learn who set up the bridgeburner to die in that cave in during the battle of Pale.
3. Finally Quick Ben wanted Hairlock dead for at least 2 reaons, 1. that Hairlock knew to much of Quick Bens plans, who quick ben was, and what powers quick ben had. 2. Because Hairlock became corupt by traveling the paths of chaos, and was already slightly unstable to begin with. (this is actually a plot point further in the series as Hairlock reappears.)